# Mounting of file systems remotely

Tags: java, unix, remote-access

1. I have a unix machine (unix1) and another remotely connected unix machine (unix2). using `sshfs` i am able to mount a unix2 file system on the unix1 machine (of course, I am the unix1 machine user and unix2 is the remote machine). But is it possible for me to mount a unix2 file system on the same (unix2) machine remotely (and not in unix1)? If so, how? Also, is it possible to do it through a java code?
2. Can i do the same with a windows machine? (unix1-windows instead of unix1-unix2)

Answer (score 0):

1. using ssh on localhost works, so why shouldn't that work with sshfs?
2. mounting shared storage from windows machine, requires samba (cifs) or nfs, so sshfs is not an option.

see
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html

Comment: This is how i gave the command as-

This will work

sshfs user@server_ip:/path/of/the/device/in/unix2 /path/in/unix1

but how to make this work?(i want to execute this from unix1 machine)

sshfs user@server_ip:/path/of/the/device/in/unix2 /path/in/unix2

Comment: if you use `127.0.0.1` as server_ip, you're not able to mount it?

Comment: mounting windows partition in windows is possible. I'm aware of that too.But how to mount the same partition in windows itself,but from linux?

Comment: and that is not the ip i'm using.

Comment: you will have to connect to windows through some utility (MobaSSH, PuTTY or similar) and then execute command `net use Z: \\remote\share\addr`

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is localhost adress, it's independent on external IP address (such as that from DHCP)